# Tkinter... Volver a una función con Botón, pero esperar click

Tags: funciones, tkinter, botón, label, retorno

Antes que nada les agradezco por todos los aportes ya que estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python de forma autodidacta y éste foro ha sido de gran ayuda. Les pido disculpas si la terminología no es la adecuada o si me extiendo mucho al explicar.
Aquí abajo pegaré un código sencillo para explicar qué es lo que quiero hacer (no es el programa en el que estoy trabajando).
En un programa en el que estoy trabajando tengo una función desde la cual llamo a otra. Ésta otra función abre una ventana secundaria, me muestra una imagen y un botón y debo esperar a que el usuario haga click en el botón para continuar con el programa en la ventana principal, donde se cargan varios Labels.
Actualmente la ventana principal muestra esos labels antes de que el usuario presione el botón y NO quiero que sea así ya que el usuario primero debe ver la imágen y recién después de hacer click se debe cerrar la ventana secundaria y comenzar a mostrar los demás labels en la ventana principal. Cabe destacar que no puedo salir de la funcion primaria o principal puesto que allí resuelvo muchos otros pasos del programa y que en realidad la llamada a ésta ventana secundaria se repite varias veces dentro de varios elif, es decir que no puedo estar cambiando a otras funciones secundarias. Todo debe estar encuadrado como en el ejemplo.
Qué estoy haciendo mal? Desde ya muchas gracias!

```
import tkinter as tk

# función secundaria
def func_sec():
    global imgfs
    # creo ventana secundaria
    ventana_sec = tk.Toplevel()
    ventana_sec.geometry("250x100")
    ventana_sec.title("Imágen")
    # miestro imágen
    lbl_sec = tk.Label(ventana_sec, text="Vamos a suponer que ésto es una imágen")
    lbl_sec.grid(row=0,column=0)
    # botón continuar 
    def continuar():
        ventana_sec.destroy()
        return
    boton_con = tk.Button(ventana_sec, text="Continuar", command=lambda:continuar())
    boton_con.grid(row=1,column=0)

# función primaria
def func_prim():
    lbl_prim = tk.Label(ventana, text="Primero Muestro ésto")
    lbl_prim.grid(row=0,column=0)
    # a función secundaria
    def ir_a_sec():
        boton_ir.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
        func_sec()
    boton_ir = tk.Button(ventana, text="Mirar Imágen", command=lambda:ir_a_sec())
    boton_ir.grid(row=1,column=0)
    # widgets que deberían mostrarse luego de presionar el botón "Continuar"
    lbl_desp1 = tk.Label(ventana, text="Luego de presionar Continuar debería mostrarse ésto")
    lbl_desp1.grid(row=2,column=0)

#ventana principal
ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Programa")
ventana.geometry('300x200')
func_prim()

ventana.mainloop()`
```

Otra cuestión que debo resolver es hacer que la ventana secundaria quede siempre encuadrada dentro de la ventana principal (por una cuestión de orden)... Cómo lo hago? Gracias!

Comment: Primero, es un placer ayudar, aunque esto NO es un foro c: Segundo, probaste con [wait_window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388346/what-does-thewait-window-method-do)?

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Dante! Perdón por lo de foro, es cierto. Estoy empezando a programar en Python por lo cual tengo poca experiencia. Vi el enlace de wait_window e intenté aplicarlo a éste código de ejemplo pero me da el error "missing 1 required positional argument: 'parent'" Podrías corregirme? Muchas gracias!
`def func_sec(parent):`
`    global imgfs`
`    ventana_sec = tk.Toplevel()`
`    parent.wait_window(ventana_sec)`

Comment: Estaba tratando de poner más bonito el código, estoy aprendiendo también a escribir posteos y comentarios aquí jaja. Gracias!

Comment: De nada! No pasa nada c: Yo al principio también pensé que era un foro. El error se debe a que en alguna parte estás llamando a la función func_sec sin pasarle el argumento obligatorio parent. Tienes dos caminos para solucionarlo: o haces que el argumento deje de ser obligatorio (quitandolo o asignandole un valor default) o pasarlo siempre que llames a func_sec.

Comment: Claro, pasa que en el ejemplo de wait_window no pasan el argumento parent. Me confunde un poco eso.

Comment: Ya veo. Por cierto, es genial de tu parte el respeto que le tienes a esta comunidad, te lo agradezco. Se suele ver más neutralidad o poca dedicación que otra cosa.

Comment: El argumento que acepta wait_window es la ventana a esperar. Y parece que wait_window es un método universal, por lo que supongo que podrías hacer eltoplevel.wait_window(eltoplevel) (ahora lo compruebo ---> comprobado)

Comment: Ok, funciona wait_window pero sigue mostrándome el label "Luego de presionar Continuar debería mostrarse ésto" antes de entrar a la ventana secundaria... Es decir, no hay variación en lo que el programa hacía originalmente.

Comment: Entiendo. Entonces debo haber entendido mal la pregunta. Por lo que no se que sea. Lo siento.

Comment: Por ahora lo solucioné creando una función de salida para cada caso en particular. Es decir, si vengo de x1 parte de mi función principal, hago `var=1` y llamo a la función secundaria. Dentro del método que resuelve el botón de continuar hay `if var==1: func_salida1()´
donde resuelvo los labels correspondientes a esa parte y para cuando vengo de la parte x2: `if var==2: func_salida2()` donde resuelvo los labels correspondientes a esa parte... Y así sucesivamente... El código no es prolijo, es muy extenso, es complicado declarar las variables que van y vienen pero... FUNCIONA ;P

Comment: Aunque, digo yo, chicos de tkinter... No sería bello un wait_button? ahhh... Nos ahorrarían tantas vueltas... Extraño las épocas de programación secuencial en Borland C ... XD